# How to use a While Loop in SQL to Create a Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In need to create an IN clause with a list of dates in it.  The list needs to be in descending order.   I created a variable named @cols and am trying to populate it with this code:

```
declare @end date='2016/05/30' 
declare @begin date = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @end), 0) ;
declare @curdate date = @end;  -- start on the last day
print @curdate;
print @begin;

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

while @curdate >=@begin  -- goes from end of the month to beginning of the month
begin
     select @cols = @cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @curdate, 106) + ']';
     select @curdate =  DATEADD(DAY,-1,@curdate ) -- subtract a day
end

print @cols;   
print @curdate;
print @begin;
```

I'm hoping to get 5/30/16, 5/29/16, 5/28/16 etc (properly formatted of course).  The code runs without error however @cols is always empty.

Comment: You should become familiar with a tally table. You should use in cases like this instead of a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `NULL` `@Cols` is because it hasn't been assigned a value before entering the while loop.  It is still `NULL`, and `NULL` + anything = `NULL`.

To remedy this, you can set `@Cols` equal to an empty string before the while loop:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX) = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing a list of dates to an IN clause? Can you not just use a simple date range such as below?

```
DECLARE @enddate = '2016-05-30'

SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE somedate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @enddate), 0)
    AND somedate < EOMONTH(@enddate)
```

Comment: This is a good idea however I need a list of dates as part of an in clause in a pivot table.